# MySQL function alias to be nested inside main array result set

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

This is for Cakephp custom query.

I've got below SQL query for MySQL database

```
SELECT g.* ,COUNT('gu.group_id') as member_count
            FROM `groups_users` as gu
            LEFT JOIN groups as g
            ON gu.group_id = g.id
            GROUP BY gu.group_id
            ORDER BY gu.group_id DESC
```

Problem with this is that it returns member_count as nested under [0] rather than part of actual main array nested under.

Is there a way we can nest it along with other result set in same array?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, can you display in an (ascii) table form what output you're getting and what output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason why it goes to [0] but it acts like when you are using $this->Model->query. Maybe CakePHP couldn't map this special alias to any model because there is no such field.

You can easily modify your result array in afterFind callback method.